# How to Auto test the Javascript Webpage

Tags: c#, javascript, automation, html

I tired to make a auto test program which can auto fill/click another webpage based application.
Want my software can eumerate the manually action, ex. click the items, fill the text box...

Now, I can load the page in C# WPF's webbrowser, but didn't know how to auto fill the javascript popup window. we cann't get the elements through funcs like GetElementId(); becasue the page seems written by javascripts.

I'm really a newer on C# and Web.Welcome everyone give comments. Many thanks!

This is the webpage I want to test:
[image]

This is the source html I got via IE->View->Source:
[image]

Comment: There is a wonderful tool already made for the process -- give this a shot: http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use such selenium and autoit tools, but they seems failed to record the js popup window. Does this tool can find the js popup window's internal controls?

Comment: I'm not one of the devs who uses it at work, so I don't know the ins and outs, but we use a number of popup divs all over the place and Selenium has no trouble finding those.